# Teams Template App error - Company communicator - We couldn't find any matches

Tags: microsoft-teams

i am deploying Teams Template App - Called Company communicator. It broadcast messages to all users or target users or teams.

I am following below deployment guide
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-company-communicator-app/wiki/Deployment-guide

when trying to send a message to teams channel or selecting specified users, Company communicator does not find any teams or users. i get an ERROR 'We couldn't find any matches'.

Same issue as https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-company-communicator-app/issues/215

Comment: Could you please check the permissions and subscriptions required to send messages as documented in the step 2 and 4. Try if that helps.

Comment: correct permissions were added to resolve it , thanks @niki

Answer (score 1):

For a Team to be visible, you must first add the "User app" to the Team. All teams where the user app will be added manually will be visible when you search for Teams in the author app.